# iOS crash report for UIKit- [UIApplication sendAction]

Tags: ios

I got crash report from Crashlytics. But I cannot find this crash where my app is. 
Do you know what this crash is related? 
Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

```
UIKit-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
0 Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xf000000c

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3b1eab26 objc_msgSend + 5
1  UIKit                          0x330f5713 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 90
2  UIKit                          0x330f56b3 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30
3  UIKit                          0x330f5691 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
4  UIKit                          0x330e111f -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 374
5  UIKit                          0x330f5107 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 590
6  UIKit                          0x330f4dd9 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 528
7  UIKit                          0x330efe65 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 832
8  UIKit                          0x330c579d -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 196
9  UIKit                          0x330c3fa3 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7098
10 CoreFoundation                 0x30919183 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
11 CoreFoundation                 0x30918653 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 206
12 CoreFoundation                 0x30916e47 __CFRunLoopRun + 622 
13 CoreFoundation                 0x30881c27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
14 CoreFoundation                 0x30881a0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
15 GraphicsServices               0x35582283 GSEventRunModal + 138
16 UIKit                          0x33125049 UIApplicationMain + 1136
17 Tapastic                       0x000f3897 main + 16 (main.m:16)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do You have exception breakpoints?

If no you should enable them by going to the break point tabs click the + and then click exception.  Run it again and it should tell you exactly where it crashes and stop the app right at that point.

If you do when i run into the problem and can't figure it out i NSLog each method when it starts and then at the crash you can check to see what method ran last and then just add more NSLogs before an after each line of code. telling you the exact spot.

Comment: This is not in Xcode. The exception was received from Crashlytics.

Comment: Oh well i feel foolish. Sorry.  As to what it was from is some deallocated object mostlikly that was tried to be used.  Probably a rare crash.

Answer (score 0):

For me I got this when I purposely added a divided by 0 statement. However the app shows the same thing OP mentioned, so I guess there can be various reasons for this.